# Error: use of overloaded operator '[]' is ambiguous

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, operator-overloading, clang

I'm getting this error with some old inherited code that previously compiled under Android NDK version r8e (GCC). I'm trying to upgrade to compile using the Android NDK version r16 (Clang).  I haven't used C++ since university many years ago, but I'm not new to programming.

The method signatures look consistent with the headers, I can't see any other operator signatures that might cause ambiguity.  I'm not sure why it's ambiguous when the parameter is clearly an `int`.  What is the cause of this error?

Commenting out one of the operators fixes the issue, but both operators are needed.

Header:

```
class XmlNode
{
public:
    // ... - let me know if you think I might have snipped anything important
    XmlNode &operator[](int idx) const;
    XmlNode &operator[](const String &name);
    // ...
};

class XmlDoc : public XmlNode
{
public:
    // snipped ... no further overrides here
};
```

Class:

```
// ...

XmlNode &operator[](int idx) const
{
    return *list[idx];
}

XmlNode &operator[](const String &name)
{
    // ...
    if(found)
    {
        // ...
        return *list[IndexOf(head)];
    }
    // not found - create new entry
    return Add(name);   // add the whole path
}
```

Code in context:

```
// ...
int idx = xml.IndexOf("METHOD");    
// ...        
MyClient::setSaveTrace(xml[idx][0].GetTextAsInt("SaveTrace", TRUE));
```

Error:

```
C:/.../myclass.cpp:3392:41: error: use of overloaded operator '[]' is ambiguous (with operand types 'KIT::XmlDoc' and 'int')
    MyClient::setSaveTrace(xml[idx][0].GetTextAsInt("SaveTrace", TRUE));
                           ~~~^~~~
C:/.../KIT-Xml.h:94:14: note: candidate function
    XmlNode &operator[](int idx) const;
             ^
C:/.../KIT-Xml.h:95:11: note: candidate function
    XmlNode &operator[](const String &name);
             ^
```

Comment: Not seeing what `String` is, can a `String` be implicitly converted to an `int`?

Comment: Excellent question - it looks like the answer is yes.  How then can I force it to pick an operator?

Comment: If the class has an `asInt` or `toInt` function or equivalent, then use that.  This is the problem with implicit conversion operators and constructors -- the compiler can do things "behind your back", making the code run differently than what you expect (assuming the code did compile with no errors).

Comment: So you're suggesting I remove the implicit int conversion in the String class and make it explicit everywhere?  I think that might work.

Comment: In addition to what has been already said: I didn't understand why `XmlNode &operator[](int idx) const` didn't "win" as it can be applied without conversion until I recongnized it is `const` the other not. Hence, a `((const XmlNode&)xml)[idx]` should fix it. (Real C++ programmers probably prefer `const_cast<>`.)

Comment: @Scheff I was so hopeful you nailed it, but it gives the same error :(

Comment: As you say it did compile before it might be a weakness of your currently used compiler. Btw. `xml` is of type `XmlDoc`? IMHO, it shouldn't make a difference but in this case I would try also `((const XmlDoc&)xml)[idx]` (as a last desperated try).

Comment: Could you change the `XmlNode &operator[](const String &name)` to `XmlNode &operator[](const String &name) const` or are there reasons why it is non-const?

Comment: Yesterday I read another question where somebody reported UB with returning non-const references (to non-const reference members) from a `const` operator. It looks similar to your `XmlNode &operator[](int idx) const`. (Though I wouldn't do this normally I cannot tell as well why this should cause UB.)

Comment: @Scheff sorry, I left that detail out.  `xml` is of type `XmlDoc &`.  And bingo - I think we're making progress!  Using `((const XmlDoc&)xml)[idx][0]` It now gives an error on the next operator down: the `[0]` - this is good!

Comment: Sorry, not sure why it's non-const

Comment: In this case: `((const XmlNode&)((const XmlDoc&)xml)[idx])[0]`. (Phew - what a monster...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting here:

```
class XmlNode
{
public:
    // ... - let me know if you think I might have snipped anything important
    XmlNode &operator[](int idx) const;
    XmlNode &operator[](const String &name);
    // ...
};
```

There are two operators: one `const` the other non-`const`.

For:

```
XmlDoc xml;
int idx;

xml[idx];
```

this is ambiguous because the compiler obviously cannot decide which implicit cast to apply.

Either:

```
((const XmlDoc&)xml).operator[](idx) // for the first
```

or:

```
xml.operator[](String::fromInt(idx)) // for the second
```

Remark:

Paul McKenzy suggested that there might be an implicit conversion from `String` to `int` causing this trouble. While writing this down, I come to the conclusion it must be the opposite – there is an implicit conversion from `int` to `String`. Without knowing better, I just called it `String::fromInt(int)` (but it might be also `String::String(int)` or anything else).

To solve the ambiguity I first suggested the explicit `const`-cast:

```
((const XmlNode&)xml)[idx]
```

but this was still not sufficient. (I'm not sure if *this* is a weakness of the specific compiler which is used.) Probably, the compiler still applies an implicit cast from `const XmlNode&` to `XmlDoc&` and thus recognizes still the same ambiguity. (It's just speculation.) Hence, my new suggestion:

```
((const XmlDoc&)xml[idx]
```

This caused progress. (The ambiguity moved to the second `operator[]`.)

Thus, the complete solution to the issue:

```
((const XmlNode&)((const XmlDoc&)xml)[idx])[0]
```

Questioner reported success.

---

I have to admit that I cannot tell whether this behavior is according to (which) C++ standard.

Comment: And as a bordering-on-ridiculous side note, since the xml nodes can be several deep, in at least one instance I had to cast like this: `return ((const XmlNode&)((const XmlNode&)((const XmlDoc&)xml_in)[Method_index])[0])[index].Text';`.  I am yet to complete the casts, but your answer has given me the information I need to go back over it and possibly find another solution that doesn't involve these casts everywhere.  Thanks again.

Comment: @pcdev No need to write everything in one line. You may introduce temp. variables to break this down. Once, applied to a `const XmlNode &xmlNode`, the const-cast shouldn't be necessary anymore when doing `xmlNode[]`.

Comment: As a follow-up, your suggestion to try changing `XmlNode &operator[](const String &name)` to `XmlNode &operator[](const String &name) const` also seems to have worked at this stage, without any casts required.  This may be a far better fix if it all works (still working through it).

Comment: Crap.  It turns out that it does need to be non-const, due to the `return Add(name);` line: I'd need to make the `Add` methods const due to a similar  overloading ambiguity, but can't because they need to assign to non-static members.